# Why ReadOnlySpan<byte>.IndexOfAnyExcept() is almost 3x as slow as ReadOnlySpan<char>.IndexOfAnyExcept()

Tags: performance, .net-7.0

Any reason why `ReadOnlySpan<byte>.IndexOfAnyExcept()` is almost 3x as SLOW as `ReadOnlySpan<char>.IndexOfAnyExcept()` ?

| Method | Mean | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ValidateDnaChar | 3.677 ms | 0.0046 ms | 3 B |
| ValidateDnaByte | 8.602 ms | 0.0239 ms | 11 B |

Performance benchmark at https://github.com/lydonchandra/PerfRefactor1/blob/e2392b2725890ffaf1f2c9e89fc20efe529e3f53/Bio/Dna/DnaBenchmark/Program.cs#L41-L50

```
private static readonly char[] DnaLowerCase = { 'a', 'c', 'g', 't', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', '\n', '>' };
private static readonly byte[] DnaLowerCaseBytes = "acgtACGT\n>"u8.ToArray();

public static bool ValidateDna(ReadOnlySpan<char> dnaSeq)
{
    var isValid = dnaSeq.IndexOfAnyExcept(DnaLowerCase) < 0;
    return isValid;
}

public static bool ValidateDna(ReadOnlySpan<byte> dnaSeq)
{
    var isValid = dnaSeq.IndexOfAnyExcept(DnaLowerCaseBytes) < 0;
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that can be improved in dotnet

TLDR: for bytes, as the byte count to search `DnaLowerCaseBytes` is less than 16 (`Vector128<byte>.Count`), execution path fell into NON-Vectorized loop, the first if statement below (file SpanHelpers.T.cs)

Adding more characters to `DnaLowerCaseBytes` to make it at least 16 bytes, performance of both are the same, as expected.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    internal static bool ContainsValueType<T>(ref T searchSpace, T value, int length) where T : struct, INumber<T>
    {
        Debug.Assert(length >= 0, "Expected non-negative length");
        Debug.Assert(value is byte or short or int or long, "Expected caller to normalize to one of these types");

        if (!Vector128.IsHardwareAccelerated || length < Vector128<T>.Count)
        {
            nuint offset = 0;

            while (length >= 8)
            {
                length -= 8;

                if (Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 1) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 2) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 3) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 4) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 5) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 6) == value
                 || Unsafe.Add(ref searchSpace, offset + 7) == value)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                offset += 8;
            }
```